# What are some reasons that can cause screenshots to take a long time (10 seconds) in OpenTest/Appium?

Tags: android, appium, appium-android, opentest

Via OpenTest, Appium can appear to take quite a long time (about 10 seconds) to capture and save the image. What are some of the reasons this might be taking so long, and are there any solutions for this slowness?

[image: screenshot of opentest log]

Answer (score 1):

10 seconds sounds like "too much", but in general it is expected that 3rd party services work slower than running test on your local machine, especially for takeScreenshot/getPageSource operations.
Multiple reasons:

- adb performance issue
- slow simulator
- 3rd party service issue

Give it a run locally and compare, then contact service questioning why it takes 5x time more :)

Comment: This was running locally on my machine.